# WEB3 error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: javascript, next.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have deployed this simple smart contract using Remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Counter {
    uint256 private count = 0;

    function setCount(uint256 val) external payable  {
        count = val;
    }

    function viewCount() external view returns (uint256) {
        return count;
    }
}
```

I deployed this contract using evm version: paris. Code has been successfully deployed and working fine on Remix IDE.

I am trying to interact this using web3.js in my next app in following way using metamask

```
const loadWeb3 = async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        const web = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });
        console.log("Accounts requested from MetaMask RPC: ", accounts);
        try {
          const contract = new web.eth.Contract(abi,contract-address);
          const transactionReceipt = await contract.methods
            .setCount(10)
            .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 3000000 });
          console.log(transaction);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(`error: ${err}`);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Please install metamask");
      }
    };
```

I was expecting that transaction would be successful but I am receiving this in my transactionReceipt

```
error: TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
 {"blockHash":"0x6138b0cdd3a047486419f066ef056aab7b28c11bbaea82b5812c095f96cf86c7","blockNumber":"1382940","cumulativeGasUsed":"21046","from":"0x9ded1ae475bd50a15dde12bbc34b7ea04969cd0b","gasUsed":"21046","logs":[],"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","status":"0","to":"0xb69254cc37d818fdbcff6501acff400913147c1c","transactionHash":"0x6d3a2d51bae3746069db1cc778b357b92a6348a37d157181943c894cfbfc0d76","transactionIndex":"1"}
```

Unable to figure out why this error is happening.

Answer (score 3):

After 3 hours of exploring, it seems that I found an answer. The code is running as expected when trying to execute code in following manner -

```
const contract = new web.eth.Contract(ABI, address);
const gasEstimate = await contract.methods
      .setCount("10")
      .estimateGas({ from: accounts[0] });
console.log(gasEstimate);

const encode = await contract.methods.setCount(10).encodeABI();

const tx = await web.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[0],
        to: address,
        gas: gasEstimate,
        data: encode,
});
```

Getting desired output when using this method of executing transaction.

Comment: Thank you for posting! This resolved the issue for me as well. The docs state that `const tx = await contract.methods.methodName(args).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 3000000 });` will work but it did not work for me. Cheers

Comment: Orignal way also works but just need to change the way of importing web3, instead of import {web3}, try using import web3.

Comment: interesting, maybe that is the issue. I'm loading web3 from a CDN using vanilla js then loading from `window.web3`.